# Como trabalhar com websockets

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html5, websocket

Estou em tentando usar WebSockets em PHP e em Javascript e estou confuso, ele usa o protocolo **ws://** e **wss://** e o servidor (a hostgator) não tem esses protocolos habilitados (eu acho!) e não consigo a conexão, alguém sabe se preciso habilitar esses protocolos no servidor ou como faço a conexão ?

Tentei conexão com outro servidor que achei em exemplos e consegui...
Segue o código (com servidor funcionando):

```
<script>

var connection = new WebSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org/')

connection.onopen = function(e) {
  alert("Connected");
  console.log("Connected");
};

connection.onclose = function(e) {
  alert("Connection closed");
  console.log("Connection closed");
};

</script>
```

**EDIT: É possível fazer streaming de áudio usando websockets ?**

Comment: Estranho, testei aqui no console do meu browser e funcionou normal

Comment: Esse exemplo é com outro servidor, no meu servidor não funciona, mas não tenho nenhum arquivo do lado do servidor para receber os dados, nem encontro nenhum exemplo de arquivo para receber os dados...Pesquisei bastante mas na verdade não entendi direito como trabalhar com websockets...

Comment: Aqui tem um tutorial bem completo http://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/websockets/basics/

Answer (score 2):

Bem, ainda não posso postar comentários =(!

Mas então, verifica se seu apache tem o modulo [proxy_wstunnel](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html) ativado, se for nginx, a primeira versão com o proxy de websocket é a 1.3.13. O tutorial postado pelo @user3230262 é massa, mas não fala de PHP, recomendo então dar uma olhada em [ratchet](http://socketo.me/).

Por ultimo, saca só essa lista de clientes e servidores que suportam a api de websockets do html5 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253683/what-browsers-support-html5-websocket-api/2700609#2700609

Answer (score 0):

O protocolo `ws://` e `wss://` não precisa ser instalado ou ativado. Este protocolo é utilizado pelo browser para auxiliar na identificação do tipo de requisição e saber tratar melhor as informações dos cabeçalho ou corpo seja durante o envio ou retorno da requisição.

Esse protocolo é novo e está disponível em browsers com suporte a conexão com websocket. Não é obrigatório o uso desse protocolo para a conexão, porem irá facilitar muito a vida.

Porem é comum executar o script do servidor em uma porta específica, pois a 80 já está em utilização pelo Apache.

Sendo assim seu endereço poderá ser ws://localhost:8080/ por exemplo.

O stream de audio ou video nada mais é do que uma transmissão de pequenas partes de arquivos entre o cliente para servidor e vice-versa. Sendo assim, basta criar um websocket que receba e transmita os dados recebidos para os clientes.