# É possível aplicar a tecnologia push?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, front-end

Tenho um sistema, em que ele exibe arquivos do banco de dados, em forma de lista.

Faço a consulta no banco de dados a cada 5 segundos para ver se existem novos arquivos, e se tiver ele é mostrado para o usuário, utilizando AJAX.

Pra que isso? Para evitar de se atualizar a pagina toda hora, para ver se tem algum arquivo novo.

Só que me aconselharam a não fazer isso, pois se tiver 100 usuários online, a cada 5 segundos 100 consultas são feitas no servidor.

Me falaram sobre a tecnologia push, e é aqui que está a minha dúvida, como implementar essa tecnologia?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19345/como-trabalhar-com-websockets, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9067/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-fazer-comunica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-cliente-servidor-em-tempo-real-via-http

Comment: Caso você tenha um ambiente controlado, você pode usar [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) + [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) para fazer esse serviço de forma muito mais eficiente.

Comment: Pesquise por: Websockets e comet programming

Answer (score 1):

Quando você precisa manter o client sincronizado com o server fazer requisições AJAX pode não ser a melhor opção, a melhor opção que temos é o uso de [sockets](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19345/como-trabalhar-com-websockets) em que ao contrário da comum requisiçao de client para server o servidor também pode "chamar" o client para dizer que algo aconteceu.

Você pode fazer sockets com PHP que no caso seriam WebSockets, infelizmente não conheço nenhum conteúdo de qualidade em português que aborde isso mas caso queira pode acessar esse projeto do github que mostra um projeto de WebSockets com PHP https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets, o detalhe é que para isso você vai precisar de acesso ao terminal do servidor linux (SSH)

Answer (score -1):

Esta imagem representa bem a diferença:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Kelvin podes comentar esta imagem para a resposta ficar mais completa?