# ajax para notificação

Tags: ajax

Para alterar o html sempre que for alterado uma informação no banco sem refresh(estilo as notificações do facebook) é feito como?
atualmente estou utilizando um timer, queria saber se há um jeito melhor que faça a requisição apenas quando necessário

[estou fazendo desta forma: setInterval("ajax()", 60000);]

Comment: setInterval é uma maneira, outra é por exemplo websockets: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19345/como-trabalhar-com-websockets?s=6|0.0000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem diversas técnicas para manter informações atualizadas com o servidor. Essa que você tá fazendo, é uma delas, e é perfeitamente aceitável.

Existem outras formas mais atualizadas, porém que possuem certas limitações quanto à navegadores. Uma delas é os [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/WebSockets).

Dá maneira como você está fazendo, você fica pedindo informações ao servidor em um intervalo regular de tempo. Isso dá a impressão de a aplicação ser `real-time`. Porém, suas requisições são feitas a cada 60 segundos. E se uma informação for alterada no banco logo após a última requisição? Ela só vai ser atualizada depois de vários segundos. WebSockets mantém uma conexão aberta entre o servidor e o cliente, de modo que o servidor pode checar por si mesmo novas informações, e enviar ao cliente quando precisar. O cliente estará de prontidão para receber essas informações, e atualiza-las na DOM, ou aonde for.

Comment: muito obrigado, vou ler sobre o WebSockets, me ajudou basntante.